# What are the codes at the end of some Event Viewer messages?

Tags: windows-event-log, eventviewer

I am trying to find the cause of some errors in the Windows Event Log I get after a crash. At the end there are two codes. Example:

```
NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.1433 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A097772) (80131506)
```

What are these? The crash has an event id (1023), but the last number also seem to be some kind of id. The first though seems to be quite unique because I basically cannot find anything on this number.

Answer (score 1):

The 80131506 refers to a [Core Execution Exemption](http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd306/refdocs/System/types/ExecutionEngineException.html), which isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Those error codes are helpful to Microsoft engineers if you file a support case with them.